# Error loading MySQL after some time

Tags: java, mysql, timer, refresh

I'm creating an application which loading from Database(MySQL) data using JDBC. My application is working fine for a period of time (approximated to 50 minutes). The program is using timer so i can refresh some JFrame to show changes in database.

The problem is that after some time it shows error loading from the database , and its not showing error loading a specific table but loading tables randomly.

I'm using this code to load from Database , and i'm using it multiple time for many tables of my Database

```
package Mysql;


public class SQLRoom {
public Connection con = null;
public Statement statement= null;
public String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
public String username = new String("bonis");
public String password = new String("bonis");
static String dbname = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/pbx";

public String selectRoom_ExtByRoom_Room(String room) {
    try {
        Class.forName(JDBC_DRIVER);
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(dbname,username,password);
        statement= con.createStatement();

        String query = "select * from room where room_room = '" +room+"'";

        String phoneNumber = null;

        final ResultSet rs1=statement.executeQuery(query);
        while (rs1.next()) {

            phoneNumber =rs1.getString("room_ext");

        }
        return phoneNumber;

    }
    catch (final Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"SQLRoom selectRoom_ExtByRoom_Room  room:" +room+" room length"+ room.length());
        return null;
    }

}

}
```

Any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right thing to do is :

```
    if (con == null){
        try {
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(dbname,username,password);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    if (statement == null){
        try {
            statement= con.createStatement();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }`
```

Cause although i did what vhunsicker said after some time it was also crashing

Answer (score 1):

Be sure to close your `statement` when you exit the try-catch block using `finally`. Same for your `connection`. Better and faster was to reuse the `connection` and close it at the end of your program.

In java 7 you can do it this way:

```
try (Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(dbname, username, password);
      Statement statement = con.createStatement()) {
   ..CODE..
}
```

In older java:

try {

```
    //YOUR CODE

  } catch (final Exception e) {

     //YOUR CODE

  } finally {
     try {
        if (statement != null) {
           statement.close();
        }
     } catch (SQLException e) {
        // error handling
     }

     try {
        if (con != null) {
           con.close();
        }
     } catch (SQLException e) {
     // error handling
     }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you open a fresh database connection with every timer tick, never releasing it again - this will drain the available connections until they reach zero.

Make sure you open your DB connection only once, then reference it in every timer tick.

Comment: If you call `selectRoom_ExtByRoom_Room` you create a new database connection. If you call it from a timer, you create a new database connection every tick. The culprit is `con = DriverManager.getConnection(dbname,username,password);`, which should check first, if `con` is already a valid connection